# Unable to display images inline using Django templates

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates, django-email

I am trying to display images inline into mails with Django but it does not work.

Here is the line that I use to display the images inline :

`<img src='http://localhost:8000/static/myproject/media/mypic.jpg' width="125" height="120" style="display: block; border: 0px;" />`

I got nothing actually....

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: More an HTML/CSS question than a Django one - suggest you retag this ...

Comment: You need to debug it. Check if `<img>` is actually in the page, then check if image source loads properly (e.g. open URL in your browser). Update your question if you found something.

Comment: I tried to open the image url in a browser it works perfectly :/

Comment: So the img tag is there and source is set correctly and source loads in browser? If yes probably a CSS/HTML issue, you can't see the image because something is on top of it or it's invisible for a reason.

Comment: So page template or **email**? How do you check/view this email message?

Comment: I understood the problem ! It comes from Google actually ! Google breaks the image ! Actually if I go to the developper console I have that : 

`https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/ndCJZyKi8xebRpdBhxw5A2k4_XqjJ6D6EdJGqpG2yn68lUhhMB3jejRdiXJksPE9pBJ8Ob3_fcBlgGelc4n2ANMsdjnCk7cH=s0-d-e1-ft#http://localhost:8000/static/myproject/media/mypic.jpg`

Comment: And if I remove that and replace by `http://localhost:8000/static/myproject/media/mypic.jpg` it works perfectly... now I don't undersand why I get that problem...